# Guessing next K values of a sequence

Tags: time-series, sequence, prediction

Say we have sampled a function in a constant rate and recieved x1,...,xn then we are requested to guess the next k values xn+1,...,xn+k, is it a known problem? is there a known algorithms or approaches to deal with that kind of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not well specified.

Who says, the next elements are *not*: 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, pi, ...

Any sequence of integers is mathematically equally likely, unless you specify your problem more precisely.

(Also, "data mining" is probably the wrong terminology. This is a TV "intelligence test" puzzle problem, not so much a real data problem.)

Comment: if the sampled data is so far matching a sinus wave it is more likely that it would continue to match the sinus wave, hence suggesting P next dots of a sinus wave is considered better then giving some const or random suggestions

Comment: What if my generator was `if x < 10: return sin(x) else: return 42`? Why should this be less likely? Mathematically, it's one sequence like any other; so you do have to specify some requirements, such as smoothness, periodicity etc.
In many situations returning `x_n=x_n-1` is your optimal guess, once you add in such requirements without knowing anythning about your use case.